# how to call a method that returns NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I have create a method which I would like to create a NSMutableAttributedString that is partly bolded. However I am having some trouble calling it to return the data that it should.

This is how I have implements the code

```
//.h
// creates bold portion of the labels in toolbar
- (NSMutableAttributedString *)createBoldString:(NSString *)labelString intRangeA:(int)rangeA intRangeB:(int)rangeB;





//.m

       - (NSMutableAttributedString *)createBoldString:(NSString *)labelString intRangeA:(int)rangeA intRangeB:(int)rangeB {
            // iOS6 and above : Use NSAttributedStrings
            const CGFloat fontSize = 12;
            UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize];
            UIFont *regularFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];
            UIColor *foregroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            // Create the attributes
            NSDictionary *attrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   boldFont, NSFontAttributeName,
                                   foregroundColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
            NSDictionary *subAttrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      regularFont, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
            const NSRange range = NSMakeRange(rangeA, rangeB); // range of " 2012/10/14 ". Ideally this should not be hardcoded

            // Create the attributed string (text + attributes)
            NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText =
            [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:labelString
                                                   attributes:attrs];
            [attributedText setAttributes:subAttrs range:range];

            // Set it in our UILabel and we are done!
            return attributedText;
        //    [firstToolBarLabel setAttributedText:attributedText];
        }
```

and this is how I am trying to call it without sucsess

```
NSAttributedString *firstAttr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] init];
    [firstAttr create.... // this dose not auto complete and I cannot see the method
```

I dont know why but I cannot use the method I created. Am I doing it right? is there a different way to pass the data back or am i missing something

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You want to call `[self create...]`, not `[firstAttr create...`]. Your `create...` method is an instance method of your object (self). It *returns* an attributed string, but it is not a method *of* the attributed string class.

Comment: +1. No need to alloc an NSAttributeString on the caller, either. Your method will return one. `NSAttributedString *firstAttr = [self create...]`

Comment: Matt, off-topic note: There's a [Meta discussion about self-promotion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182212/what-signifies-good-self-promotion-or-self-promotion-part-infinity) where I've mentioned you as a good practicioner of such. You may be  interested in reading or weighing in.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'm not really promoting anything, at least not in the sense of selling. The entire book is available for free online as Web pages, and that's what I'm pointing to. I just wish people would *use* what I've written, in the cases where it answers their questions. They might learn something, and it would save bandwidth. In other words, I'd like my writing to be a resource that people learn from. To me, that's a good goal, in sync with what Stack Overflow also does.

Comment: That's pretty much what I said, _especially_ the part about people learning something on their own from your book. But there are definitely -- if you don't already know this -- some users here on SO who think any linking to your own stuff is anathema. "Self-promotion" is the figure of speech that's used on Meta to discuss it.

Comment: My feeling is that where I've already spent years writing a much better and fuller explanation of something than can I can include in a small Stack Overflow answer, with downloadable example code, it is appropriate to mention that fact. I am not promoting myself, I'm promoting knowledge. Perhaps I should not be irked by the repetition of the same questions over and over on Stack Overflow when I feel I've already provided an excellent answer and explanation, but I am. If our Benevolent Masters have a better solution to the wasted bandwidth, what is it?

Comment: Matt, I'm sorry, I didn't mean to start an argument with you. I respect your contributions here, the work you put into your book(s), and, as I said, especially your idea of directing people to resources where they can help themselves. I apologize if you feel like I've cast you in with some pack of unscrupulous self-aggrandizing ruffians; I had hoped you would take my mention of you as a compliment.

Comment: As for the question of repetitive questions, well, that certainly does come up for discussion a lot, and there's no 100% resolution. In particular, a fellow named [Pekka](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/138112/pekka) puts a lot of thought into the problem, and comes up with, in my opinion, some stellar ideas, which unfortunately mostly go unimplemented. My favorite is [Another take on canonical answers add a canonical vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116087). [General reference questions create low quality dead ends for googlers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160565) is related.